Spyder Python package not found for pyROOT
I am trying to use pyROOT (Python version of CERN ROOT) using Spyder on my Ubuntu Linux machine. I have found the pyROOT (or so I think) directory to add to Spyder using the Tools, PYTHONPATH manager by entering the following command into the pyROOT dedicated terminal such that:
>>> import pathlib, ROOT; pathlib.Path(ROOT.__file__).resolve().parent
PosixPath('/snap/root-framework/931/usr/local/lib/ROOT')

Still, after adding the paths to the PYTHONPATH manager
/snap/root-framework/931/usr/local/lib/ROOT/_pythonization
/snap/root-framework/931/usr/local/lib/ROOT

I still get the error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ROOT'. How could I fix this issue?
